# Installing fix_yahoo_finance without pip in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am learning Python and use Anaconda navigator 1.8.7 and Spyder 3.3.0 (Python 3.6.6 32 bits, QT 5.9.4, PyQt5 5.9.2 on Windows). I would like to install a package called 'fix_yahoo_finance' without using pip since I have read that pip creates problems for Anaconda users.

I know that this is the line of code used when using pip:

```
   pip install fix_yahoo_finance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

When I tried using 
    conda install fix_yahoo_finance 
and I get a 'Solving environment: failed'

How do I get this package without using pip? Is there an alternative way that I could run this package in Anaconda like placing it in the pkgs folder?? I am absolutely confused and would really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually install it from other way around as well, clone this repo into your local system.

`git clone https://github.com/ranaroussi/fix-yahoo-finance.git`

Then go to the directory `fix-yahoo-finance` or any dir that you have cloned the repo. Then run `sudo python3 setup.py install`

This way too you can install the package without using pip, but make sure your python is pointing to the Anaconda's python, otherwise the only way to install it would be to copy the package folder from the site-pacakges and paste inside the Conda's package folder. Also you can look around your conda install error, https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6390

Comment: How do I clone this into my system?

Comment: I copied and pasted the file downloaded from https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/#files and I copied and pasted it into Anaconda3/pkgs but when I try to import it, it does not work.

Comment: Apologies I realised I copied and pasted it into the wrong folder. Will try site packages

Comment: It still didn't work. Maybe I have done something wrong ?

Comment: Clone it anywhere you want, with the same git clone command as I've given in the answer and run setup.py install. This will install the package.

Comment: Windows 10 is the one

Comment: Oh Ok, I hope your have git installed and accessible in the terminal. You can also download a zip https://github.com/ranaroussi/fix-yahoo-finance of this repo, and run python setup.py install inside the exctrated directory.

Comment: Hi @user2906838. I have ultimately done some reading and have used pip in the Anaconda prompt rather than my Command prompt. I do not have git installed as yet but will do some time later and will try your method for other packages. Thanks a lot for your help.